# Hibernate reverse engineering of a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping, postgresql-9.2

I am having some trouble generating my DAO/POJO code using **Hibernate** for a **PostgreSQL** database written using the **CamelCase notation**. Everything works fine until the code generation time: only my lowercase tables are generated!

If I have a table called `Person`, the Hibernate Configurations View will show it but without any attributes. Say I have another table, `car`, it will be shown with all of its attributes. On code generation time, furthermore, `car` will appear in the destination package, while the CamelCase tables won't, as it is completely ignored.

[I found a way](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HBX-1000?focusedCommentId=38018&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-38018) of overriding the default metadata generation class (`JDBCMetaDataDialect`), but it doesn't work. Even if it did work, I think my POJO/DAO objects would not work, because the `PostgreSQLDialect` dialect would handle the lowercase tables (and attributes?) in a wrong way.

How can I solve this issue? It looks like a bug, but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up always returning true from my generation method:

```
public boolean needQuote(String name) {
    return true;
}
```